# Can't boot from CD on mac because broken trackpad

Tags: mac, boot

I want to boot a cd from my mac on startup.  I believe this is done by holding down "c" with the CD in the drive.  However, my trackpad is broken.  The mouse button is permanently pushed down.  This ejects the CD on startup.  I tried plugging in an external mouse, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okie, here is the solution. Ignore the trackpad when mouse is present. It's done from Universal Access in versions older to Mountain Lion. In Mountain Lion its in Accessibility. Im am attaching a screenshot to help you find it. Just click on the check box. Then boot with the CD holding down Option Key on your keyboard. Once the external mouse is attached, trackpad will be ignored / disabled.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the option key when booting. This will bring you to a screen where you can select startup drives. Once you get there, insert your cd, and wait for it to appear. (This may take a while.) Once the cd appears, select it, and your computer will boot from it.